# Get the original value of link in jQuery and update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like it so that I can "add on" to a `href`. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    // get the link currently
    var linkCurrent = $("#link").attr("href");
    // update link
    $("#link").attr("href", linkCurrent + "/added");
    // show the link
    $("#newLink").text($("#link").attr("href"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com" id="link">Link to google</a>
<input type="button" value="Click me many times and look at new link" id="btn">
<p id="newLink">new link</p>
```

Something like that, but what I want to know is that does jQuery offer a way to get the current attribute value and then automatically append to it? Or do I got to store in a variable like I did above?

Comment: No need to store that in a variable if you are just appending it. Instead of storing it to a variable directly use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) method with callback as follow

```
$('#link').attr('href', function(i, oldHref) {
    return oldHref + '/added';
});
```

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $('#link').attr('href', function(i, oldHref) {
    return oldHref + '/added';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com" id="link">Link to google</a>
<input type="button" value="Click me many times and look at new link" id="btn">
<p id="newLink">new link</p>
```

The callback accepts the `index` and the current value of the attribute(`href` in this case). The returned value is used to update the value of the attribute.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `index i`?

Comment: @KSplitX It is sometimes used when there are multiple elements in the DOM and you want to perform operations on specific elements. Ex: Updating the attributes of even `li` to something and odd `li` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    // update link
    $("#link").attr("href", $("#link").attr("href") + "/added");
    // show the link
    $("#newLink").text($("#link").attr("href"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com" id="link">Link to google</a>
<input type="button" value="Click me many times and look at new link" id="btn">
<p id="newLink">new link</p>
```

No need to store that in a variable if you are just appending it. Instead of storing it to a variable directly use that.

It is your wish to use a variable. Variables are used for simplicity in code, rather than typing it again.

Comment: Thats basically something I like to avoid (refering to it directly), thats why i like Tushar's answer